# Is it possible to modify the Chrome or Firefox developer tools network page?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

Both Chrome and Firefox provide "Network" pages in their DevTools, which are very useful. I'm working with software which adds headers to HTTP responses to communicate performance information. I would like to be able to see this information at-a-glance in the Network panel, but looking at the relevant Chrome and MDN docs, I can't see any way to modify existing DevTools panels.

Is it possible to do this? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

Both Google Chrome and Firefox allow you to modify the shown columns and to show specific header values. It seems however that only in Chrome you can also add custom headers.

To do so, open the Network tab in the Dev Tools and make sure there is at least one entry in the list. Then right click on one of the table headers (like Name, Path, Method, etc.) to open the context menu that allows you to select which columns you want to show. From this context menu go to "Response Headers" -> "Manage Header Columns...". Then in the modal that pops up click "Add custom header..." and enter the name of the header you want to show. Click "Add" and it should now be part of the overview table.

In Firefox it works the same, but you can only select one of the predefined headers.

[image: Image of the context menu]

Comment: Thank you, this is a useful workaround for now. I would still like to make a slicker interface (e.g. color-coded pills, etc.) and to be able to do this in Firefox, but I will accept this response later if nobody else comes in with more info about the other aspects of the question.

Comment: For Firefox there is an old feature request for that at https://bugzil.la/1377013.